# A case when $fg=0$ as well as $f\bar{g}=0$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-numbers, lp-spaces, fourier-transform, projection

I wonder how the second last sentence can be deduced. That is, $(f-Pf)\cdot Pg=0$. Here, $e_\alpha(t) = e^{-i\alpha t}.$ I don't believe that such things as whether a complex vector space is closed under complex conjugation would be used. Thus, I thought that some simple algebraical manipulation such as $\overline{Pg} =Pg_r - iPg_i $ would be applied to some line in the below to deduce the statement, but I could not find where the point would be hidden. Also, I guess that some other fact might be to be used.

[image]

Comment: I am much embarrassed due to the abrupt downpoints, which is the first situation for me. :( Is there something somewhat unacceptable mathematically or in manner? Please let me know.

Comment: The product of two complex numbers is $0$ if and only if one of the factors is $0$. Also, $b = 0 \iff \overline{b} = 0$. Hence $a\cdot b = 0 \iff a \cdot \overline{b} = 0$.

Comment: Ha.... I see. My question deserved to be downpointed. Should I delete the silly question?

Comment: I don't consider "somebody overlooked something easy" as grounds for downvoting, so I disagree with the "deserved". If you think your question can help future visitors, post an answer to it rather than deleting it. Otherwise, since nobody posted an answer yet, you can delete it if you prefer to do that.

Comment: I think somebody could be stopped by the same question, though it would be rare. Thus, I will not delete it. Thanks :)